# На что больше тратить время: JavaScript или JQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вопрос собственно следующий.
На что тратить больше времени при разработке скриптов, на чистый JavaScript (без JQuery) или же на JQuery? т.е. стараться разрабатывать скрипты без использования JQuery или наоборот только с использованием JQuery. Синтаксис у них отличается!

спасибо заранее.

Comment: сначала javascript (без DOM) а потом всё что угодно. синтаксис у jQuery и javascript отличаться не может, т.к. используя jQuery вы пишите на js.

Comment: вопрос в стиле "на какой язык тратить больше времени - на русский или матерный?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если для начального изучения, то лучше чистый JavaScript с хорошим знание DOM и CSS. В этом случае вы закрепляется знание основ того, как все работает. Библиотеки являются некоторыми готовыми решениями на JavaScript, поэтому их синтаксис полностью базируется на JS. Если вы хорошо знаете JS, то проблем с освоением других библиотек(не только jQuery) не будет, на изучение JQuery у меня ушло два-три дня.

JQuery - это библиотека для кроссбраузерной работы с DOM-деревом и событиями. В реальных боевых проектах, в которых требуется работа с данными элементами, лучше использовать ее. Так вы получите более оптимизированные функции и уменьшите количество потенциальных ошибок на своей странице. Но, например, при работе с каким-нибудь Canvas эта библиотека практически бесполезна, для построения готовых элементов лучше YUI, для проектирования ООП - mootools, для графиков Raphael и т.д. Чистый JavaScript - только если очень критичен трафик или надо сделать совсем простые действия.

Comment: а можно спросить, что означает "хорошее знание DOM" ? это понимание отношений родители-потомки-сиблинги и т.д. + знание в каком порядке дерево DOM загружается - или что то еще? я щас просто тоже JQuery понемногу, хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: 1. Что такое дерево: узел, родитель, потомки, сиблинги, типы узлов(текст, блоки).
2. Что у каждого узла есть свойства, которые отвечают за информацию о нем и его внешнее оформление. 
2.1 знать, что узел хранит html атрибуты(node.id, node.width, node.name)
2.2 знать, что узел хранит css атрибуты (node.style.*)
2.3 знать, что есть еще другие свойства
3. Что у каждого узла есть методы(такие как document.getElementById()), события (load, mouseclick, mousemovie) и  их наступление. 
4. Знать основные элементы дерева верхнего уровня: window, history, location, document, form, link

Comment: @Alexey123 спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Alexey123 ну вот какое отношение `document.getElementById` имеет к js ?

Comment: @eicto, язык JavaScript не является самостоятельным языком и служит для управления внешним окружением(на сервере, в браузере, в игровых движках, как различные плагины и т.д.). В данном случае автор поста подразумевает управление web-страницами в браузере, а это подразумевает как раз прямую работу непосредственно с DOM-деревом и модификация всего перечисленного в нем. Если не знать, чем можно управлять в браузере, то зачем тогда нужно учить язык применяемый специально для этого? Конечно можно, но пользы мало от того, что его нельзя применить.

Comment: ох. dom методы это не только js и смысла их изучать нет особого - трата времени (есть jQuery, есть angular и не надо про "надо знать как на самом деле там в браузере это вызывается" - не надо знать, вообще, если сам не собрался фреймворк писать.). На крайняк  - есть справочники в которых все очень понятно описано. А вот познать асинхронную и прототипную модель, работу с событиями, отличие контекста от области видимости,  и вообще особенности языка весьма полезно. вопрос на засыпку - как вы думаете почему dom и вообще браузерное API описано в спецификации **HTML** ?

Comment: @eicto, а потом берутся люди, которые не могут сделать простых вещей выходящих за рамки использования этих библиотек или начать работать с тем же Canvas. К тому же я не говорил прямо их заучивать, просто понимать как это устроено, что занимает очень непродолжительное время и с лихвой окупается в дальнейшем.

Comment: Как раз наоборот, потом берутся люди которые думают что знают js, хотя выучили только API которое к js отношения по сути не имеет. И не могут простейших вещей понять типа конструкций this.on('event',(function(i) {return function() {console.log[i];};})(i);

Comment: Не задумывался, но думаю спецификации HTML __созданы для разработчиков браузеров__, что бы они могли основываясь на них строить унифицированные интерфейсы доступа и правильное поведение элементов на странице. Соответственно HTML преобразовывается в DOM-дерево при отображение и позволяет к нему обращаться, это взаимосвязано.

Comment: Что касается Вашего замечание, я не говорил учить только DOM, я говорил совместить изучение JavaScript и понять, что такое DOM. Кстати Ваш код поставит в тупик своим console.log(), которого в языке JavaScript нет, к тому же знание DOM избавит от чувства того, что многие объекты включены в сам язык как таковые. И если вы против того, что бы разработчик JS познакомился с DOM, то хотя бы опишите причины по которым так думаете.

Comment: спецификации HTML созданы для разработчиков браузеров c одной стороны и программистов с другой (как описание протоколов, чтобы написать клиент или сервер мы читаем один и тот же документ) в тупик как раз не поставит, для нормального программиста js console - некий объект, а log это его метод, в общем-то неважно что оно делает. (так-же как и this.on())  Я не против изучения DOM, только это называется не js программист а фронтенд разработчик. Замечание я вам сделал как-раз из-за того что вы перечислили пункты API а не js, про js вы не сказали ни слова.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery это кросс-платформенный (мульти-браузерность, если хотите) framework java script. Если сказать простыми словами - инструмент, призванный облегчать как написание, наглядность так и читаемость разрабатываемого кода на java script.

Comment: ну т.е стараться разрабатывать скрипты используя всегда JQuery?

Comment: если нужна скорость при разработке проектов - однозначно да.
Но тут не идет речь о том, что только jquery. Это только лишь библиотека, которая помогает в разработке.
Например, Вам, не надо будет думать в ряде случаев, как поведет себя тот или иной браузер при написании определенного кода.
Удобно же написать, "выбрать все элементы определенного класса" одной строчкой: 
$('.class1').text('Текст для элементов определенного класса');

Есть аналоги JQuery, но они не так удобны, на мой взгляд. Да и эта библиотека лдинамично развивается.

Comment: В общем, от поставленной задачи вы должны сами проанализировать, стоит ли использовать jQuery или писать все на чистом JS. К примеру ради одной функции (какого нибудь селектора с кликом) не стоит добавлять библиотеку.